# How to parse JSON in where clause (SQL Server)

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I am trying to parse a column

**Example Column Data**

```
[{"id":"100190","role":"Company"},{"id":"1049","role":"Person"}]
```

**Example Table**

```
| item | perm                                                             | 
|------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| a100 | NULL                                                             |
| a101 | NULL                                                             |
| b200 | [{"id":"100190","role":"Company"},{"id":"1049","role":"Person"}] |
| b201 | [{"id":"100190","role":"Company"},{"id":"1049","role":"Person"}] |
```

**Example Procedure**

```
declare @id int = 1049

select *
from someTable
where contains(openjson(perm, '$') with (
  id int '$.id'
), @id)
```

**Expeced Output **

```
| item | perm                                                             | 
|------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| b200 | [{"id":"100190","role":"Company"},{"id":"1049","role":"Person"}] |
| b201 | [{"id":"100190","role":"Company"},{"id":"1049","role":"Person"}] |
```

How do I select rows that contain a given id from an embedded array of JSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using CROSS APPLY on your JSON will get you what you want.

Here's an example you can run in SSMS:

```
-- Create table --
DECLARE @Data TABLE ( item VARCHAR(10), perm NVARCHAR(MAX) );

-- Add sample data --
INSERT INTO @Data ( item, perm ) VALUES
( 'a100', NULL ),
( 'a101', NULL ),
( 'b200', '[{"id":"100190","role":"Company"},{"id":"1049","role":"Person"}]' ),
( 'b201', '[{"id":"100190","role":"Company"},{"id":"1049","role":"Person"}]' );

-- Create id param --
DECLARE @id INT = 1049;

-- Select rows where JSON.id equals @id --
SELECT
    d.item, d.perm, j.id
FROM @Data AS d
CROSS APPLY (

    SELECT id FROM OPENJSON( d.perm ) WITH (
        id INT '$.id'
    )

) AS j
WHERE
    j.id = @id
ORDER BY
    d.item;
```

Which returns:

```
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
| item |                               perm                               |  id  |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
| b200 | [{"id":"100190","role":"Company"},{"id":"1049","role":"Person"}] | 1049 |
| b201 | [{"id":"100190","role":"Company"},{"id":"1049","role":"Person"}] | 1049 |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `OPENJSON` to parse JSON array and CROSS APPLY to filter rows:

```
declare @id int = 1049;

select t.*
from t
cross apply(select * from OPENJSON(t.perm, '$') WITH (id INT '$.id') where id = @id) sub;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6f831a9daadaab7fb93427b4fa822593)**